Find maximum, minimum, supreme and infimum of : $A_n = \{ f'(a) : f(x) = x^n \text{ and } a \in (0,1) \}$
Someone can please help me out with this exercise, I have to find the minimum, maximum, supremum and infimum of:
$A_n = \{ f'(a) : f(x) = x^n \text{ and } a \in (0,1) \}$
I calculated the derivative: $ f(x) = x^n $ with respect to $ x $ then $f'(x) = n x^{n-1}$ which is the value of the derivative at a point  $a \in (0,1)$
Analysis of $ n a^{n-1}$ when $ a \in (0,1) $:

When $ a \to 1 $, $ n a^{n-1} \to n $.
When $ a \to 0^+ $:

If $ n > 1 $, then $ a^{n-1} \to 0 $, so $ n a^{n-1} \to 0 $.
If $ n = 1 $, then $ f(x) = x $, and $ f'(x) = 1 $, thus $ A_1 = \{1\} $.
If $ 0 < n < 1 $, then $ a^{n-1} \to \infty $, and $ n a^{n-1} $ diverges to infinity.



Not sure if that is correct , and I don't know how I can find maximum, minimum, supreme and infimum, please help.

It is a good beginning :
You have to calculate, on the conditions they exists the quantities :
$$ \inf A_n \ ; \ \sup A_n $$
In order to do this. Let now see that that as you see the case $n=1$ is done, then for the others consider :
$$ a \to na^{n-1} $$
This application is increasing if $n>1$ decreasing elsewhere. So because the interval $(0,1)$ is open we won't talk about min and max but about infinum, supremum. (For recall, a min is an attained infinum).
So as a general results for $n>1$ :
$$\inf A_n = \inf_{a} na^{n-1} = 0 $$
$$\sup A_n = \sup_{a} na^{n-1} = n$$
As $0<n<1$ :
$$\inf A_n = \inf_{a} na^{n-1} = n $$
$$\sup A_n = \sup_{a} na^{n-1} = + \infty $$
If you want $\min$ and $\sup$ problem, convert $(0,1)$ into the closed set $[0,1]$ which will be only when $n\geq 1$.
